# Broad VF range of LED... 5-9V?

Tags: voltage, led

I'm not quite sure what to do with this LED, it's got a forward voltage rating of 5-9V, so I've got a lot of wiggle room and I'm not sure of the ideal (or even if there is an ideal) voltage at which to drive it. Here is the datasheet info. Perhaps someone can tell me how they think I should drive it. I know I'll be using two lithium cells in series, so because of the broad range in this LED's VF I can either drive it directly until the 6V cutoff, or regulate it with a buck to a a certain voltage. Thanks a heap[image: ![Spec1[![][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL7vK.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCvXv.jpg) 
[[image: spec2]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnKtK.jpg)

Comment: Drive it with constant current like any other LED. 100mA seems reasonable; at least stay below 150mA.

Comment: That’s really wide! You nonetheless need to drive it with constant current.

Comment: You might find my notes on [Datasheet current](http://lednique.com/datasheet-current/) and [Variations in Vf and "binning"](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/variations-vf-binning/) worth a read. Most of it has been republished here in various posts.

Comment: Look at the table titled "Forward Current vs. Forward Voltage", then ask yourself what would happen if you drove the diode at the wrong voltage.

Comment: I'm making a flashlight, so I was just planning on using a current limiting resistor instead of buying a constant current driver. I just need to determine a certain voltage number to set my buck converter at. I'll definitely give it a read, transistor. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @TimWescott This graph is pure fantasy. How can the current move up vertically at 7.2V? LOL.

Comment: @Fredled: you're supposed to understand that a diode's response is exponential with voltage, and that once the current gets above "way too much" the graph is allowed to be a bit inaccurate.

Comment: @TimWescott Yes, but I'm confuse with the exact typical voltage at 150mA. According to this grap, it's 7V (below I stated 9V). But even so it shouldn't skyrocket like this past the treshold.

Comment: And it shouldn't be near 0mA at 5V neither.

Comment: Why not?  It's a diode, whose current is proportional to the **exponent** of its forward voltage.  The current could reasonably be expected to double for every rise in 20mV, and halve for every such drop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't drive an LED with a voltage source.

You need to use a current source at up to 150mA

A resistor from a voltage significantly higher than the LED voltage is usually acceptable for low power applications although the current won't be as well defined as a proper current source.

The data sheet is telling you that when you drive the LED at the specified current (150mA in this case) the voltage across the LED could be anywhere between 5V and 9V.

If you use a voltage source such as 9V there could be enough variation between devices such that one operates correctly whole another has much higher current that exceeds the safe limit for the device thus destroying it.

Similarly, if you used 5V some LEDs would give out the specified amount of light but another might not give very much at all. The behaviour will also change over temperature or as the LED warms up during operation.

Comment: I'm driving it with a voltage source and a current limiting resistor, I've never been a fan of having to buy a module or board if all I need are some resistors, correct me if I'm wrong. So do you think something along the lines of 6-8V would be more appropriate, just to get away from either extreme?

Comment: @JaredCravens - You can make a current source with a transistor and a few resistors. Although a simple series resistor will work you will not be able to set the current as accurately as the device  to device variations will cause a larger current change. If you are feeding it from a current source you don't need to worry about the max voltage - you let the LED find it's own level (btw that will change with temperature).

Comment: Got it. Thanks Kevin.

Comment: @Kevin White At 50mA " the voltage across the LED could be anywhere between 5V and 9V." It will be, most of the time, very close to 9V. The 5V is only an indication for normal use. Not for a specific current.

Comment: @Fredled - Not according to the data sheet. A typical device would do as you say. It clearly says at the top of the table Vf@150mA. So a device that had 5V @ 150mA would still meet the specification. I agree it is very unlikely.

Comment: @Kevin White Normally the typical voltage should be much more precise. Or it's a special product with such characteristic. Not a normal led.

Answer (score 3):

You don't drive it with a particular voltage.

You use a constant current source set to whatever current level you need for the LED to be bright enough for your use.

The [datasheet](http://www.inolux-corp.com/datasheet/Inolux%20UV/IN-C39(X)TK%20UVC%20Series%20V1.2.pdf) says the LED is rated for a maximum of 150mA.

You'll want a constant current driver that can supply at least 9V, but that limits the current to no more than 150mA (less if you need a lower intensity light.)

---

That is a UVC LED. Please make sure that you won't be exposed to it.  UVC can damage your skin and eyes - and that seems to be a very powerful LED.

Comment: 9V is the max. Isn't that a bit risky? Yes I do know to be careful with it, but at $60 I'm glad to know it's powerful. I wasn't sure how powerful it was in comparison to other SMD LEDs because it's not really a lumen type of scenario.

Comment: @Jared, According to the datasheet, if you want 150 mA you might need to provide 9 V. If you use a source that can't supply 9 V, you might not get 150 mA. But 150 mA is also an abs max rating, so if you want this thing to last a long time, you probably don't want to drive it all the way to 150 mA.

Comment: @JaredCravens The LED uses a lot of power, but the conversion efficiency is very low (few percent), so you're only getting a few milliwatts which is not much light. That is good from a safety perspective, but if you were hoping to sterilize surfaces or generate fluorescence this isn't a good choice.

Comment: Okay, thanks y'all.

Answer (score 0):

You can be safe with 6V, directly. If there's only one LED per power supply you can connect your led directly without any current regulation. But don't try the same with 8 or 9V. At 6V you will have less light than at 9V but you will be within the safe area. If you have several LED in parallel, you need to add 1/4W resistors (exact resistance can be calculated but it should be around 30ohm or so). You can also power two leds in serie with 12V (most common power supply) or 4 leds with 24V. Also without any current control.
If you want maximum light for your LEDs then you will need a constant current power supply of ecxactely 150mA, able to give 3W. This is less common but not impossible to find.

Comment: Why will a 6V supply give me less output than an 8V supply? As long as it's drawing 150mA...?

Comment: First as stated above 150mA is a maximum. I don't recommend using it at max if you want to keep them long tem for many many hours. For short durations (a few minutes) and strong intensity, once in a while, it may be ok. But not for massive or professional usage. So 120mA may be better. As stated above, for 150mA you need at least 3W or  a range up to 10V (9V minimum). For 120mA slightly less.

Comment: If you use a constant voltage (instead of constant current) power supply, 6V will give you less "output" than 8V but it will be safer (as I understand these leds are exxpensive). How many amperes it will draw is then unkown and irrelevant. If you use a constant current supply, then the amperes will always be the same, and the voltage becomes irrelevant.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I'd be considered as using a constant current as I'll just be using a battery (or series of batteries) and a current limiting resistor. But are you saying this LED will have a higher output at 8V@130mA than it will at 6V@130mA?

Comment: No: With constant voltage supplies, at 8V it may use (that's my guess) 140mA (near maximum), at 6V it will be closer to 120mA or even 100mA. At 5V you will use maybe just 80mA and so on. But you will never know because it's not exact science. But amperes depends on voltage. If you use a constant current supply, you will always have the same amperes and then you voltages will be likely 9V if you use 150mA and 6V if you use 100mA, etc. It's the reverse calculation. The constant current supply adapts the voltage to always get fixed current.

Comment: I would never suggest driving an led directly with a voltage... even if it looks like it's acceptable from the datasheet.

Comment: It's perfectly safe if you stay well below typical voltage for said current. In this case, if the led draws 150mA at 9V and it's safe to do so, then it will draw +-100 mA at 6V and there is no chance it draws more than 150 mA. What you cannot do is trying to drive this led with constant voltage at 9V because then it can draw 200mA instead of 150mA and you start having problems.. @MadHatter

Comment: if you look at the Min and Max voltage spec for 150 milliamps, you will see that some LEDs may pull as much as a 150mA at 5 volts, so 6 volts would blow it up. You can not just use the graph. That is nominal and does not show worst case or normal variation of manufacturering...

Comment: @MadHatter This is not the voltage range for 150 mA but the voltage range in which the led is usable with reasonable output. 150mA is the maximum allowable and this is theorically done with 9V. Variation of manufacturing should be in the order of 0.5V in the worst cases, maybe 1V with aging and bad working conditions. Quality manufacture would offer variation of only 0.1V. It's pretty accurate. These variation are very small but an inaccurate voltage regulation will cause a huge swing in consumed current.

Comment: So if the voltage for 150mA is 8.9V instead of 9V, and you regulate the supply at 9.1V, you may have 180mA instead of 150mA just by this 0.2V difference. And it's enough to cause overheating. That's why constant current is necessary at or near the maximum current allowable. But at 6V, there is no chance that it produces 150mA. Probably not even at 8V. Current falls very sharply and exponentialy with voltage. My guess is that at 6V you get less than 100mA.

Comment: According to the graph provided the typical voltage for 150mA would be 7V. Not 9V as I said before. By experience I noticed the typical voltage is close to the maximum voltage in the range. In this particular case the variability may be bigger.

Comment: I have yet to see you quote any statistical information in any of your comments. I would say this data sheet does not give the statistical variation of their manufacturing population. You are probably correct, but I wouldn't design high quality product I'm being probably correct.

Comment: @MadHatter My answer has to be taken in the context of a hobbyist asking help on a basic led circuit. For mass production of market-ready, quality products, I agree with you. But in this case, constant current supplies are inbedded in the product and designed secificaly for this product, You may not find the constant current supply for the exact current and power that you need (two parameters have to match) at the stores. That's why a solution with a classical constant voltage supply may be useful.

Comment: I have no "statistical information" because I speak of experience. Of course I haven't tested all the leds in the market and not this one. I always observed that applying the lowest voltage mentioned on such datasheet had a very dim effect. I think they put the limit lower than real for safety. Or they observed it in the most extreme situation, I don;t know,